# Android SlidingDrawer default state?

Tags: android, android-widget, slidingdrawer

I'm currently having trouble with a SlidingDrawer. I want it to be closed when the application starts so it doesn't get in the way. However, it is determined that it will be open, despite putting `slide.close()` in the onCreate() of my activity. It seems to be closed if i use `slide.animateClose()` instead, but this slows my application down loads.

How do I make it closed by default?

Cheers

```
    <SlidingDrawer 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="4dp" 
    android:id="@+id/Mnu_Slide" 
    android:content="@+id/Mnu_SlideCont" 
    android:handle="@+id/Mnu_SlideBtn" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
    android:layout_height="112dp">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@id/Mnu_SlideBtn" 
        android:src="@drawable/handle1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@id/Mnu_SlideCont" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/tray1xml">
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/Mnu_Chem" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/Mnu_Physics" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/physicon" />
    </LinearLayout> 
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with that. It looks very similar to my own `SlidingDrawer` code (which I've included in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654492/android-can-height-of-slidingdrawer-be-set-with-wrap-content)) and that always starts closed, with no need to close it explicitly in the `onCreate()` method.

I suspect it might have something to do with whatever this view is lodged inside: is it by any chance in a `LinearLayout`? Try changing it to a `RelativeLayout` instead. The [docs for SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) are a bit vague but they do say:

> SlidingDrawer should be used as an
>   overlay inside layouts. This means
>   SlidingDrawer should only be used
>   inside of a FrameLayout or a
>   RelativeLayout for instance.

Hope that helps.