# Android: can height of SlidingDrawer be set with wrap_content?

Tags: android, layout, slidingdrawer

I'm trying to implement a `SlidingDrawer` that will occupy the full screen width, but whose height is determined dynamically by its contents: in other words, standard `fill_parent` layout behaviour for the width and `wrap_content` for the height. That's exactly how I've specified it in the layout XML (see below) but the sliding drawer always opens to the full screen height. The height of my content varies, but typically it's only about half the screen height, so I end up with a big gap underneath it. What I'd like is for the content to sit neatly on the bottom of the screen.

I've tried everything I can think of to fix it but nothing's worked so far. If I set the `SlidingDrawer`'s `layout_height` to a specific value (e.g. `160dip`) it works, but that's not what I need: it has to be dynamic. Of course I've made sure all the child elements have their height set to `wrap_content` too.

The documentation on SlidingDrawer is a bit vague on this and I haven't been able to find any examples that do what I'm after either. If anyone can see where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate your help!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/ImageFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </ViewFlipper>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/infoDrawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:handle="@+id/infoDrawerHandle"
        android:content="@+id/infoDrawerContent"
        android:allowSingleTap="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Sliding drawer handle -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/infoDrawerHandle"
            android:src="@drawable/info_handle_closed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- Sliding drawer content: a scroller containing a group of text views
        laid out in a LinearLayout -->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@id/infoDrawerContent"
            android:background="@drawable/info_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/infoDrawerContent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="5dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/infoTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/infoCreator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14dip"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/infoDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffcc00"
                    android:textSize="14dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/heading_pro_tip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/infoProTip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffcc00"
                    android:textSize="14dip" />

            </LinearLayout>    

        </ScrollView>

    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The `onMeasure()` method of the SlidingDrawer class basically overrides the layout modes to `fill_parent`, this is why `layout_height="wrap_content"` is not working.

To get around this, you can extend SlidingDrawer with a re-implemented `onMeasure()` method that honors the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes. You can then use this custom class in your XML layout by replacing `<SlidingDrawer ...>` with `<fully.qualified.package.ClassName ...>`.

Note that since the drawer will no longer be filling the parent layout, you will have to enclose it in a LinearLayout with the gravity attribute set to the edge where the drawer should be.

Below are a class I have created for this purpose and an example layout.

WrappingSlidingDrawer class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;


public class WrappingSlidingDrawer extends SlidingDrawer {

    public WrappingSlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        int orientation = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "orientation", ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
        mTopOffset = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "topOffset", 0);
        mVertical = (orientation == SlidingDrawer.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    }

    public WrappingSlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        int orientation = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "orientation", ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
        mTopOffset = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "topOffset", 0);
        mVertical = (orientation == SlidingDrawer.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSpecSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSpecSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SlidingDrawer cannot have UNSPECIFIED dimensions");
        }

        final View handle = getHandle();
        final View content = getContent();
        measureChild(handle, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mVertical) {
            int height = heightSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredHeight() - mTopOffset;
            content.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, heightSpecMode));
            heightSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredHeight() + mTopOffset + content.getMeasuredHeight();
            widthSpecSize = content.getMeasuredWidth();
            if (handle.getMeasuredWidth() > widthSpecSize) widthSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
        else {
            int width = widthSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredWidth() - mTopOffset;
            getContent().measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, widthSpecMode), heightMeasureSpec);
            widthSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredWidth() + mTopOffset + content.getMeasuredWidth();
            heightSpecSize = content.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (handle.getMeasuredHeight() > heightSpecSize) heightSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(widthSpecSize, heightSpecSize);
    }

    private boolean mVertical;
    private int mTopOffset;
}
```

Example layout (assuming WrappingSlidingDrawer is in package com.package) :

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    ... stuff you want to cover at full-size ...
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.package.WrappingSlidingDrawer android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:content="@+id/content"
                           android:handle="@+id/handle">
            ... handle and content views ...
        </com.package.WrappingSlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Great stuff! I struggled for weeks with this sliding drawer issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fantastic: thanks for such a detailed answer and sorry it took me so long to get round to accepting it!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I'd give you +100 if I could.

Comment: This is great, however, how do I align something to fill the screen until the handle? the way it works now, the linearlayout is on fill width and height, so i can't fit anything else on the screen...
any tips? I want to just have something that covers the entire screen and then at the bottom of it, I'd like to have a handle that will only open up to the content it needs to show...
In other words - I'd like to align an element to be above the handle - is that possible using this method?

Comment: Please read my answer too: this solution has a minr issue. See also the answer from museofwater

Comment: +1 - This is just want I needed.  I was able to get around needing an enclosing LinearLayout by assigning a layout_gravity to the WrappingSlidingDrawer.

Comment: I have used this and working fine, but the problem is that when i close the sliding drawer. space remain shame of the sliding drawer.my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408430/android-sliding-drawer-remain-space-as-it-is-after-close-it

Comment: super job. helped a lot

Answer (score 5):

just set to pmargin in sliding drawer in your xml

```
android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
```

Answer (score 5):

seydhe's answer has a small issue.

The first argument to the getAttributeIntValue needs to be the full namespace, not just "android".  So the code snippet should be:

```
final String xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
int orientation = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(xmlns, "orientation", SlidingDrawer.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
 mTopOffset = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(xmlns, "topOffset", 0);
```

I was having trouble getting this to work with a horizontal sliding drawer until I realized that it was not finding the orientation attribute and was therefore treating it as vertical.

Comment: This shouldn't have been an answer. Suggest an edit instead.

Answer (score 4):

it is better to read the parameter without hardcoding the string:

```
    int attrOrientation = android.R.attr.orientation;
    int attrTopOffset = android.R.attr.topOffset;

    int[] attrIds = new int [] {attrOrientation, attrTopOffset}; 

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrIds);
    int orientation = a.getInt(0, SlidingDrawer.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    topOffset = a.getDimension(1, 0);
    a.recycle(); 

    isVertical = (orientation == SlidingDrawer.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

Another issus is in the onMeasure.

I used the following code:

```
    if (isVertical) {
        int height = heightSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredHeight() - topOffset;
        getContent().measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSpecSize, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        heightSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredHeight() + topOffset + content.getMeasuredHeight();
        widthSpecSize = content.getMeasuredWidth();
        if (handle.getMeasuredWidth() > widthSpecSize) widthSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredWidth();
    } else {
        int width = widthSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredWidth() - topOffset;
        getContent().measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSpecSize, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        widthSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredWidth() + topOffset + content.getMeasuredWidth();
        heightSpecSize = content.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (handle.getMeasuredHeight() > heightSpecSize) heightSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
```

Comment: +1 - I used the first improvement to avoid hardcoding.  One minor change I had to make was how to get the topOffset value:  topOffset = (int) a.getDimension(1, 0);

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately you can't set the height, but rather the opposite of that.  the topOffset attribute will determine how tall to make the sliding drawer, but its what to shave off rather than how tall it will be.

Comment: Actually I did manage to set the height (as I've mentioned above) by giving an explicit height to the SlidingDrawer: looks like the topOffset solution is another way to achieve the same thing. (I've also found examples where this is done, but so far none using wrap_content.)

Comment: this guy's panel widget lets you set the height with wrap_content among other nice things http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
private SlidingDrawer rightSlidingPanel = null;

 @Override 
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
...
    rightSlidingPanel = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById( R.id.rightSlidingPanel );
    rightSlidingPanel.post( new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    rightSlidingPanel.getLayoutParams().width = findViewById( R.id.sliding_content2 ).getMeasuredWidth() + findViewById( R.id.sliding_handle ).getMeasuredWidth();
                }

            });
}
```

XML Layout:

```
...
    <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/rightSlidingPanel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:allowSingleTap="true"
            android:animateOnClick="true"
            android:content="@+id/sliding_content"
            android:handle="@+id/sliding_handle"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sliding_handle"
                style="@style/toolbar_button"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:height="40dp"
                android:text="&lt;"
                android:width="25dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_content2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

...
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
...
```