# How can i limit the size of a sliding drawer?

Tags: android, size, position, slidingdrawer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: can height of SlidingDrawer be set with wrap_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654492/android-can-height-of-slidingdrawer-be-set-with-wrap-content)

Is there a way to change the size of a sliding drawer when it opens ? And is there a way to place it in the top, or in the left, because the default option are bottom for the vertical orientation and right to the horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654492/android-can-height-of-slidingdrawer-be-set-with-wrap-content) about overriding `SlidingDrawer#onMeasure` to enable `wrap_content` for `SlidingDrawer` seems like a winner.

> The `onMeasure()` method of the
>   `SlidingDrawer` class basically
>   overrides the layout modes to
>   `fill_parent`, this is why
>   `layout_height="wrap_content"` is not
>   working.

**Edit** - Or, you can set the height exactly in with something like `layout_height="200dp"`.

Your other question was already [answered in the negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137350/how-to-make-an-android-slidingdrawer-slide-out-from-the-left).

Comment: but i was thinking something more like this one [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-sliding-drawer-tutorial)

Comment: Sure, that looks like a good idea too. You can try it easily by just setting an exact layout_height on the SlidingDrawer

Comment: the problem was that my linear layout didn't have a gravity   android:gravity="bottom" .