# set sliding drawer height dynamically

Tags: java, android-layout, android, slidingdrawer

I would like to define the height of sliding drawer height dynamically or statically whatever.
Below is my xml layout file. Any suggestion would be appreciate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_movie"></ImageView>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#C0C0C0" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: can height of SlidingDrawer be set with wrap_content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654492/android-can-height-of-slidingdrawer-be-set-with-wrap-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the height to a specific height such as `200dp`, or you can use something like [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654492/android-can-height-of-slidingdrawer-be-set-with-wrap-content/4265553#4265553) if you want to use `wrap_content`.

Comment: hey matt, i tried already with set height to 200 dp but it doesn't working as well, slider just move to the center of screen when i set layout_height attribute to 200 dp. Any ideas ?

Comment: You mean, it's no longer attached to the bottom of the screen? It could be that your FrameLayout has not set its layout_height to fill_parent, and also you may have to set android:layout_gravity="bottom" on your SlidingDrawer

Answer (score 1):

just set to pmargin in sliding drawer in your xml

```
android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use topOffset attribute for SlidingDrawer.

like this...

```
<SlidingDrawer 
...
android:topOffset="800px"
```