# Android : How to set Sliding Drawer topOffset/bottomOffset at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer, layoutparams

I came across this `topOffset` attribute of a `Sliding Drawer`. It seems pretty useful, but I would like to set it at runtime.

Is this possible?

I looked through the developer docs, couldn't find much.

Comment: Have a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654492/android-can-height-of-slidingdrawer-be-set-with-wrap-content worked just fine for me.