# Android : SlidingDrawer & wrong display

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have to use SlidingDrawer in my app. I know this class is deprecated but it very useful to do what i want so i have decided to use it.

I've used this link

[Android: can height of SlidingDrawer be set with wrap_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654492/android-can-height-of-slidingdrawer-be-set-with-wrap-content/4265553#4265553)

in order to use wrap_content when the SlidinDrawer is open. It works perfect on android 4.2.2 with AOSP rom but with android 4.0.4 on SGSII (Samsung rom), i have some display problem when i open or close the SlidingDrawer. If there is no action, the widget appears correctly.

Have you any idea why there is this problem ?

Edit : Here is a screenshot. The problem disappeared when i took a screenshot, so to see the problem i took a photo with another device.
[image]

Comment: Deprecated widget should not be used as they are deprecated due to some reason. Don't use that. Instead there are also custom sliding drawers available. use them.

Comment: I've not found any library which let me to do the same thing easily

Comment: can you show me sliding drawer image so that i can help you other option for sliding drawer?

Comment: It's just a sliding drawer which is at the bottom and which opens when the user clicks it. I will post an image later because I have not the phone for the moment.

Comment: I have added an image to show the bug. Has you another option for SlifdingDrawer ?

Comment: i didn't find any sliding drawer here ... is it gone?

Comment: Yes, the sliding drawer is gone (this is the bug). Here, we can see only the blue line but the sliding drawer must display from the blue line to the bottom

Comment: see my answer. have you tried to implement it?

Comment: Not yet. I'm watching the code

Answer (score 1):

Alternate to SlidingDrawer is "Custom Sliding Drawer".

[Sephiroth](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/) has created one of it. It has option to sliding up and down. It has handler which is used like actual handle to open and close Sliding Drawer.

I will suggest you to implement this custom one. This will solve your problem.

You just need to define following in your layout

```
<view class="it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer"
     xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     my:direction="topToBottom"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     my:handle="@+id/handle"
     my:content="@+id/content">

     <include android:id="@id/content"
         layout="@layout/pen_content" />

     <imageview android:id="@id/handle"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
</view>
```

Thats it. Your sliding drawer is ready to work.

Comment: Is it a way to use wrap_content for the height of this custom sliding drawer ?

Comment: i think you should give exact "dp" height to your drawer. For each screen size you can provide it and this will not "wrap" after initialization.

Comment: It's okay, I find the solution for the height but I have the problem again for the display. If I open up, i can see the content but when i want to close it, the content disappears ... And the problem persists on my SGS II with android 4.0.4 whereas it works perfectly on Galaxy NOte with android 4.2.2

Comment: my friend, I never use deprecated things. It is deprecated due to some reason. and that is why I search for alternative. I can't help you in inbuild SlidingDrawer.

Comment: arf ! It's strange, I find it's a nice widget but i agree if it is deprecated it's maybe, there are too problems with it ...